# Getting the error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" when trying to use whisper-merge

Tags: python, graphite, whisper

I'm trying to use [whisper-merge](https://github.com/graphite-project/whisper) to merge 2 `wsp` files.  They have identical retention strategies, one just has older data than the other.

When I run `whisper-merge oldfile.wsp newfile.wsp` I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/src/whisper-0.9.12/bin/whisper-merge.py", line 32, in <module>
    whisper.merge(path_from, path_to)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/whisper.py", line 821, in merge
    (timeInfo, values) = fetch(path_from, fromTime, untilTime)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Any ideas?

Here's the meta data output for the 2 files:

- "from_file" http://sprunge.us/dBHC
- "to_file" http://sprunge.us/eIVG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snippet from `whisper.py`

```
def fetch(path,fromTime,untilTime=None):
    """fetch(path,fromTime,untilTime=None)

    path is a string
    fromTime is an epoch time
    untilTime is also an epoch time, but defaults to now.

    Returns a tuple of (timeInfo, valueList)
    where timeInfo is itself a tuple of (fromTime, untilTime, step)

    Returns None if no data can be returned
    """
    fh = open(path,'rb')
    return file_fetch(fh, fromTime, untilTime)
```

Suggests that `whisper.fetch()` is returning `None`, which in turn, (along with the final line in the traceback) suggests that there is a problem with your `path_from` file.
Looking a little deeper, `whisper.file_fetch()` appears to have two places where it can return `None` (explicitly, at least):

```
def file_fetch(fh, fromTime, untilTime):
    header = __readHeader(fh)
    now = int( time.time() )
    if untilTime is None:
        untilTime = now
    fromTime = int(fromTime)
    untilTime = int(untilTime)

    # Here we try and be flexible and return as much data as we can.
    # If the range of data is from too far in the past or fully in the future, we
    # return nothing
    if (fromTime > untilTime):
        raise InvalidTimeInterval("Invalid time interval: from time '%s' is after until time '%s'" % (fromTime, untilTime))

    oldestTime = now - header['maxRetention']
    # Range is in the future
    if fromTime > now:
        return None               # <== Here
    # Range is beyond retention
    if untilTime < oldestTime:
        return None               # <== ...and here
    ...
```

Comment: That seems likely, however the from file renders fine in graphite

Comment: Meta data for "from_file" http://sprunge.us/dBHC
Meta data for "to_file" http://sprunge.us/eIVG

Comment: There are only two obvious places where the `None` could come from (there may be some non-obvious ones). Maybe a couple of debug `print`s in `whisper.file_fetch()` would narrow it down?

Answer (score 7):

Line 812 in whisper.py is broken for files that contain multiple archives.
https://github.com/graphite-project/whisper/blob/0.9.12/whisper.py#L812

```
fromTime = int(time.time()) - headerFrom['maxRetention']
```

To fix, immediately following line 813, assign fromTime based on the archive retention.
https://github.com/graphite-project/whisper/blob/0.9.12/whisper.py#L813

```
for archive in archives: # this line already exists
  fromTime = int(time.time()) - archive['retention'] # add this line
```

Comment: Jason, thanks a lot for the suggestion,  I faced the same issue today with latest stable Graphite. I think you should open a bug and propose the change to Whisper :)

Comment: The related issue exists now: https://github.com/graphite-project/whisper/issues/163